# Random Number Generator Bias Edited

Tags: probability, statistics

A scientist is wondering if his random number generator is faulty. The generator outputs integers from 0 to 999. He speculates that the generator has a bias to generate numbers that are close to 300, 450 and 600. So, for example, the generator may produce 580 more often in the long run than 750 because 580 is closer to 600 than 750. He generates 3 numbers to test his suspicions. They are...

$$595\\ 635\\ 894$$

Unfortunately, he cannot generate more than these 3 numbers at this time and must derive a probability that the generator is biased or not based on only these 3 numbers.

Bias will be defined as any above zero tendency for the rng to be unfair. Any level of favoritism, no matter how slight, to generate numbers close to 300, 450 and 600 would constitute bias. Zero favoritism would constitute a lack of bias.

What is $p_\text{biased}$ and $p_\text{not biased}$?

I've tried the following...
The average distance of any random value generated this way will be 136.2 units away from which ever number of 300, 450, and 600 is closest if the generator is fair.

I also found the standard deviation and variance for a fair generator. Standard Dev = 111.0 closeness to closest value.
Var = 12322.88 closeness to closest value.

Plugging these values into a z-score calculator i get a p-value of 0.348 for a one tailed hypothesis test. Its saying there is a 34.8% chance that the generator is not biased.

Is this solution correct? 
Any alternate approaches or thoughts about this?

Comment: It is not *"saying there is a 34.8% chance that the generator is not biased"*  At best it is saying that if there was no bias then there would be  $34.8\%$ chance that the result you could have seen would have been as or more extreme than the one you did see (I have not checked the numbers).

Comment: This is a fairly arcane problem ... 595, 635, and 894 are the three numbers drawn and you are trying to assess whether a bias exists towards numbers around 300, 450 and 600.  I'm wondering if you might use a Bayesian method here to represent the fact that he has suspected these three peaks (with accuracy +/- 25 perhaps).  He must have developed this suspicion by having seen previous sets of data and the analysis ought to leverage this prior knowledge to some extent.